# Create dummy objects for classes using JMockit

Tags: java, unit-testing, jmockit

I'd like to create dummy objects ([see definition here](http://martinfowler.com/articles/mocksArentStubs.html)) using JMockit.

These objects are required as nonnull constructor arguments, but aren't needed for the specific unittest. Because the constructor might check the parameter (e. g. using `Objects.requireNonNull`), the dummy can't just be `null`.

I'd like to use something like

```
new ObjectWithUnusedDependency(dummy());
```

where `dummy()` creates a dummy object.

Using

```
public static <T> T dummy() {
    return new MockUp<T>() {}.getMockInstance();
}
```

this might work if `T` is an interface, but for classes `getMockInstance` returns `null`.

It would be nice, if the test would fail when a method is invoked on such a dummy object.

Is there a way to accomplish this using JMockit?

Comment: Would not any effect free, non null instance work?  So if the constructor's signature was `(Integer x)` and x could not be null but was not otherwise used, then you could use `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (or anything).

Comment: It might work in some special cases. But in most cases such an object is not as easy to create as a simple `Integer`. If it has dependencies on its own, they get tied transitively into the tests dependencies.

Comment: I see.  I assume its dependencies are also null-checked?

Comment: I prefer Mockito.  I can mock classes and I will get a non-null mock.  For final methods, the mock will use the behavior defined in code.  For other methods, the mock will not do anything (return null), unless I specify a behavior.  So I don't use constructors at all, I just make all my methods final and I can test them by mocking an instance of their containing class.  I am free to specify the behavior of any abstract methods.  All my methods are either abstract or final.

Comment: Yes, the dependencies also have null-checking constructors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very easy to do with JMockit. Simply declare a mock field or mock parameter of the desired type, and pass it to the code under test. For example:

```
@Test
public void myTest(@Injectable SomeClass dummy)
{
    new ObjectWithUnusedDependency(dummy).doSomething();
}
```

Works for any reference type, including `final` classes, `abstract` classes, interfaces, enums, etc.

If, in addition, you want the test to fail in case any methods get called on the dummy object,  a "full verification" needs to be added:

```
@Test
public void myTest(@Injectable SomeClass dummy)
{
    new ObjectWithUnusedDependency(dummy).doSomething();

    new FullVerifications(dummy) {};
}
```

Comment: This is obviously the intended way of getting a mock object. But the declarative approach is not very readable, especially when multiple different dummy objects are needed.

Comment: Do you have a suggestion as to what could possibly look more readable?  Annotations such as `@Mocked`, `@Mock`, `@Injectable`, etc. are generally regarded as the "modern way" for introducing all kinds of test doubles; all Java mocking APIs have them, even EasyMock and jMock now.

Comment: I totally agree with you that annotations are good for mock objects (there should only be a very small number of mock objects for a single test). But for a dummy object that is just needed to fulfill the requirements of a constructor, the syntax is a bit too bloated. It should be enough to just have a call to a static method, at most with a class argument. A "perfect" solution would be like your second code snippet but without `@Injectable` method parameter and with implicit `FullVerifications` on all used dummies. `dummy` would be just one method call.

Comment: Well, to me a dummy is just a mock object which doesn't get used by the SUT. And I don't see why making one method call is better than annotating one field/parameter with one annotation; in fact, the annotation approach is simpler, because you only write the type once, while with the method approach you have to write it *twice*:  `Dummy dummy = createDummy(Dummy.class)` versus `@Mocked Dummy dummy`.

Comment: If one could use type inference as shown in the question (`return new MockUp<T>() {}.getMockInstance();`), the class would not have to get mentioned at all, but the `createDummy` method could be used in line. This would result in `new ObjectWithUnusedDependency(dummy()).doSomething();` (mind the brackets) without all the other clutter around. And if there was an _implicit_ empty `FullVerifications` on the dummy, one could save another line of code.

Comment: Ok, but that's not possible in Java (and every other language, I think, as it requires the `dummy()` method to obtain, at runtime, the declared type of another method's parameter, at the call site). Also, verifying no invocations on the dummy qualifies it as a *mock*; for a real dummy, you wouldn't care.

Comment: You are right, it is not possible in Java (due to type erasure). But using a static `dummy` method as shown in the question (extended to accept a class parameter `Class<?>` and passing it through to the `MockUp` constructor), I reach 90% of what I want. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

I think your mocking framework should handle this for you.  So in my humble opinion, the real solution is to change mocking frameworks.

However, if you will not change mocking frameworks this is still solvable.  Use javassist - http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/

Your code will look like this

```
import javassist.util.proxy.*;

     ProxyFactory f=new ProxyFactory();
     f.setSuperclass(Dummy.class);
     Class<?>dummyClass=f.createClass();
     Dummy dummy=(Dummy)dummyClass.newInstance();

     new ObjectWithUnusedDependency(dummy);
```

If you do this a lot, it would be smart to create helper methods like
`public static <T> T dummy(Class<T>clazz)`
to DRY those four lines of code so you will get:
`new ObjectWithUnusedDependency(dummy(Dummy.class))`.

It is like `java.lang.reflect.Proxy` except you can also proxy classes.

I think you will still have problems with final classes and system classes (java.lang.System, java.lang.Math, etc.), but if your class needs a non null reference to a java.lang.Math instance then it probably won't work in production - no need to unit test.

Comment: Any mocking framework can create dummy objects. Not all of them can do so for any type, though, as you mentioned. (For Java, only JMockit and PowerMock can.)